# Javascript doesn't work as expected but i don't know why

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

i just start learning Javascript. I have the following code but it doesn't work. I don't know why :(.I also don't know how to debug this.

```
var test = [[1, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [2, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [3, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']];
var scrore = 0;
teststart(test);
function testtart(a){
    for ( var i = 0, question, answer; i < a.length; i++ ) {
        question =  'Question ' + a[i][0];
        answer = ask(question);
        check(answer, a, i);
    }
    gameOver();
}
function ask(st) {
    return prompt(st);
}
function check(x, y, z) {
    if ( x === y[z][1] ) {
        alert('Correct answer!');
        score++;
    } else {
        alert('Wrong answer!');
    }
}
function gameOver() {
    alert('Game Over! You scored ' +  score + ' points!');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct & match your function name & variable name

like

```
teststart(test);
function testtart(a)
var scrore = 0;
score++;
```

change

```
teststart(test);
function teststart(a)
var scrre = 0;
score++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
teststart(test);
function testtart(a){
```

should be:

```
teststart(test);
function teststart(a){
```

Your function name is missing an `s`

as user Antiga pointed out in the comments you also have a typo in your initialization of the variable `score`

```
var scrore = 0;
```

Should be:

```
var score = 0;
```

Comment: Opps! sorry everyone for my negligences. Thank you!